# Why was this question deleted? I can find neither spam nor rude/abusive behavior in it

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

The explanation to my newly acquired privilege of viewing deleted posts says:

> Make sure what is being deleted should have been deleted, and bring unnecessary or harmful deletions to the attention of the community and/or moderator team.

I've just encountered a deletion with a reason that sounds weird to me, that's why I'm opening this meta question.

---

I'm talking about this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62985017/please-programmers-help-me-because-am-totally-confused

> This post is hidden. It was deleted 2 mins ago by Jean-François Fabre♦.
>
> This question was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details.

The original question was:

> Please programmers, help me because am totally confused
>
> Please programmers, I purchased only domain for $15 on godaddy with no hosting which I totally regret and transferred to my heroku. Now, my portfolio website is not secured and I don't know what to do. Please someone should enlighten me because am a newbie and I think I just wasted $15 on only domain without ssl. Please what do I do?

The user was just asking for help and after it was deleted I did check the revision history to see if maybe they got frustrated and edited the post to something rude, but it doesn't seem like it. Neither do I see any spam, they were referring to GoDaddy and Heroku but it was part of the question and not advertisement (quite the opposite, the user was wondering if they wasted money).

Was it a mistake that this question was deleted as spam or rude/abusive or am I missing something?

---

Clarification: It's **not** about whether it was on-topic or not, or should have been closed or not, or whether it should have been deleted at all or not. (Although I was surprised that it was already deleted and not just closed.) I was mainly wondering why the deletion reason was "spam or rude or abusive" while I think that none of those reasons applied here.

Comment: It had an active spam flag at the time of deletion. If a question or answer has an active spam or R/A flag when it's deleted, it gets that overlay. The severe consequences of 6 R/A flags from users or 1 from a mod only happen if the post is deleted by Community. Doesn't seem to be on-topic for SO though, but it isn't spam. It wasn't strictly deleted as spam either. You are allowed to share the content of the question. There's cases where that's not a good idea (like if that was real spam, which it isn't), but that's really case-dependent and you won't get suspended for it or anything

Comment: The question definitely wasn't suitable for SO. Domain purchases are off-topic. Suggesting better alternatives for domain hosting are also off-topic. What do you want to achieve with this posts? Do you think it should be undeleted?

Comment: No I was just trying to understand what was going on. I have the privilege to see deleted posts (and therefore their reason of deletion) only since today. Before the question went away, I felt divided between whether it's on-topic or not, because I understood that the solution for the user would have been how to get free SSL working on Heroku (and I was about to post an explanation with several options, referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185560/heroku-set-ssl-certificates-on-free-plan) which is also on SO), and imo that technical aspect is on-topic.

Comment: I was then just very confused about the deletion reason that was displayed ("spam or rude or abusive"). That's why I asked, because I thought maybe someone clicked the wrong option somewhere during deletion, or maybe I'm misunderstanding what it means, or maybe there was something happening in the question that I didn't notice and that I can't see (or didn't figure out how to see) despite my 10k rep privilege.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand now that the deletion reason carries less meaning than I thought.

Comment: Perhaps someone would be kind enough to post an image of the pertinent parts of that question for those of us who don't yet have the reputation that allows us to see deleted posts?

Comment: Oh, sorry - added it to the question, now that I learned it's OK to do so.

Comment: it has only a link in it and else not much context, that is not enough for a [good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean exactly? My question, or the question in question? Because my question had a lot of context, while the question in question didn't have a link. So I'm a bit confused what you are referring to.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I didn't flag the question as spam (else my name wouldn't be associated to the deletion), but I deleted the question, which automatically validated a spam flag cast by a regular user.

It's not spam, but the question is blatantly off-topic and unsalvageable. I deleted it right away, instead of following the "long" process which is close, then let roomba delete it.

Quoting [Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) (our former CM) in the moderator room:

> So my advice is... If you come across a post that's bad on every possible axis, don't waste any time or effort trying to figure out which axis it is the most bad along; just delete it.

Deleting a spam-flagged post doesn't trigger the -100 penalty by the way. It just leaves a complimentary downvote from Community user, which can weigh in for post ban but that's about it.

What I wasn't aware of is that the spam flag showed for 10k+ users. Here what moderators see:

[image]

(As noted in comments, the OP probably sees the deleted post without the spam notice too.)

I *could* have just closed the question and declined the spam flag (I usually do this on off-topic & fake spam questions). I think I read it too quickly, and the `$15` + GoDaddy name clicked and I deleted on sight.

Here's what I'm going to do:

- I'll clear the spam flag, which will remove one downvote to the question and will undelete it
- I'll close it. I doubt that it's salvageable, though.
- Maybe it should be deleted right now, to protect OP & avoid more downvotes because of the meta effect.

PS: Congratulations for getting 10k rep. Now a whole new world of bad content opens up to you.

Comment: Interesting discrepancy on what mods vs 10k users see. Might be worth bringing that up to CMs to see if devs can give mods a bit more info for views of other rep levels. Also interesting to know that clearing spam flags (even retroactively) removes the spam flag-induced downvote on posts... didn't know that previously (and not sure if it's recorded anywhere).

Comment: I knew that there was a difference for posts where a mod (or 6 users) flagged as spam/RA: mods just see "deleted by" and the full contents when 10k+ users have to click to see possibly offensive contents (SO cares for user eyes, not for mod eyes :)). This difference is there for posts that have a spam flag & are deleted...

Comment: Interesting indeed, this is how I saw the same post: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU9U1.png - So I was jumping to the wrong conclusion.

Comment: At the end of the day it is your decision, but in my opinion you could leave it deleted. When you undeleted it you only exposed it to additional downvotes, both for question and answer. If the answer gets accepted it only makes it more difficult for us to delete it later.

Comment: @Dharman I could delete it now that I have cleared the flag. But if I clear the flag first, it disappears from the mod UI... So I have to find it manually...

Comment: *"PS: Congratulations for getting 10k rep. Now a whole new world of bad content opens up to you."* -- This statement may have supreme relevance to the lucky stiffs who "win" the moderator elections in a few days, no?

Comment: "Congratulations for getting the diamond. Now a whole new world of intricate 690+ custom flags opens up to you"

Comment: A point that was just discussed in the now-deleted comment thread of Dharman's answer, which I'd like to keep around though: It seems we aren't entirely sure what is displayed to the user in the case of deleting the question this way. In case it would show a notification that it was deleted because of spam, it would be very misleading. In case it would just vanish without any explanation, it would also be less-than-ideal because we then cannot expect any improvement from the user in their question-asking, only frustration. So even though it's annoying for mods, closing may be more helpful...?

Comment: yes, close then possibly delete. That would be the way to go.

Comment: So it sounds like possibly your mod UI could use a "decline flag but close question" feature to make it easier to go the best route... I guess

Comment: closing question doesn't validate the spam flag, fortunately. But the UI could use a "decline spam flag and _delete_ question". We have that for rude comments now (decline and delete) and it's a lifesaver.

Comment: @CherryDT Some of us investigated (an Answer though) and found that the user will not be notified and does not know what there is any spam associated with their post. I assume this is the same for Questions. We speculate the reason is that the author is unlikely to be offended by their own post. The scenario was for a post that is deleted without the reputation penalty.