# Low quality answer by new contributor but deleted as spam/rude/abusive by moderator

Tags: discussion

One of the answers was deleted by a moderator saying: "This answer was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details."

[This revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64062802/revisions) does not show any fact about it. Probably this can be a link-only answer and also technically blog content is not accurate for the OP question, is that the reason?

Edit: My question is about misdirection and confused new contributor perspective. Can we inform them using some reason similar to some of the comments in this question to educate them. What if the new contributor is a hidden gem though he/she started on a wrong foot?

Screenshot for people with less than 10k reps:

[image]

Edit 2:

I was reading related posts, found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399557/7920473) which reveals about mod action in super fast mode to get rid of bad contents, there’s no way to test the OP experience on such cases without sandbox testing. But mods has more visibility and Rene comment helped me to see more background things like dupe profile, similar posting by OP before many years which got instruction to improve (that’s my motive). After these many years OP created another profile and doing same stuffs yielded spam flags and deletion. Are we sure OP got all these context, or is it just another ..poof.. it’s gone for him/her. Unless they come to meta and see this exact post or ask question about it?

Comment: It was posted by Talha Manzoor, linking to a site starting with `https://talhamanzoor`. This qualifies as undisclosed self-promotion.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I agree, but its not a paid tool or service, just a blogpost.. still I'm confused

Comment: “Probably this can be a link-only answer and also technically blog content is not accurate for the OP question, is that the reason?” - A answer that only  contains only a link to a blog sounds like spam to me.  I cannot view deleted answers on Stack Overflow but I routinely flag as spam, answers that contain a link to a blog website, on other communities.

Comment: Maybe they're making money on ads. Maybe they're trying to increase traffic to the blog by posting it on SO. Either way, their purpose is *advertising*, rather than the more innocuous accidental link-only-answer.

Comment: @SecurityHound our review queue statement says: "This is a link-only answer (and not spam)
“While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”" So non-spam link only answers need edit and not immediate delete, correct?

Comment: Check the help page for [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). One of the requirements is to always disclose the affiliation *on the post itself*.

Comment: @CertainPerformance that rings a bell.. :)

Comment: @AndrewT. I would have pasted that link in the answer and notify the answerer (new contributor) at least..

Comment: I consider an answer, that only contains a link to a blog authored by the user, to actually be spam.  Why is this answer, that was flagged as spam by other users, worth this meta question?

Comment: @SecurityHound interesting, we can add that AI and alert them while answering lol

Comment: Pretty persistent [spammer](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&username=Talha+Manzoor&site=1) that even forgot they already had an account on the site. There were at least two spam flags on that answer causing the content to be hidden from direct view when the mod deleted the answer.

Comment: @rene this is cool

Comment: though any question can be marked as dupe and some people are going to agree/vote for that, anyone even remember what is the experience as a new contributor and communication relayed here for this situation and future learning.. ?

Comment: What is confusing about being told your answer is spam as defined by SO guidelines? User will get link to such guidleines

Comment: There really is no helping a user, who submits a contribution, that contains a single sentence that is simply a link to their own blog website.  At the very least this answer, that didn’t even answer the question, would have been deleted for not being an answer.  Helping a spammer, spam is with additional content, isn’t something anyone should be doing.

Comment: @charlietfl oh okay, if they are informed about it then fine. Otherwise it’s not fair to say they are repeat offenders without conveying it by commenting or guiding them..

Answer (score 10):

I can't see the answer because I have less than 10k rep, but the fact that it doesn't involve a monetary transaction doesn't necessarily mean that it isn't spam.

That's why things like job offers are [still spam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276249/are-job-offers-spam).

Based on the comments, it looks like this does little more than promote their blog, which is excessive self-promotion.

One good heuristic: if you remove the self-promotion, would there be anything of value left? If so, then you might be able to edit to salvage it. Otherwise, it's probably spam.

Comment: I totally understand that, due to covid layoffs there are many people starting their career from scratch again globally, they may start blogging and learning, contributing to many online repositories, for the very first time. They have to learn, I'm not saying we should relax our rules.. simply of more helpful..

Comment: @ArunVinoth If they put in enough information so the answer could stand without a link and made it clear that it was a link to their site it would change things

Comment: @JoeW hindsight vs foresight is the huge gap/problem here :(

Comment: @Arun I mean..... The docs and help center are clear. The only thing we can say for the 'lack of foresight', is that the answerer doesn't check our help center

Comment: Comment by rene in question made the context very clear.. I can accept that as answer.